# php -i | find "extension_dir" don't take effect after modified its value

Tags: php

i wanna using curl in php script and run it in command line mode.

here is the script

```
<?php
 //enable_dl("php_curl.dll");
 $ch = curl_init();
 $options=array(
  CURLOPT_URL=>"http://test.com/wp-content/themes/bluefocus/images/desc_img.jpg",
  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER=>true,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true
 );
 curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $fp=fopen("test.jpg","w");
 fwrite($fp,$data);
 curl_close($ch);
?>
```

i run it in cmd with command **php get.php**

the error message:

```
D:\project>php get.php

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\project\gals_curl_batch_download\get.php on line 3
```

phpinfo() in the webpage output shows curl has been enabled

```
cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
```

and here is the strange thing 
phpinfo() int the webpage output show, in fact extension enabled in php.ini can be run in web page. the exact directory of the extension is under ./ext

```
extension_dir ./ext ./ext
```

but php -i | find "extension_dir" always show this and can't be modified with in php.ini file

```
extension_dir => C:\php5 => C:\php5
```

restarted apache several times, keeps the same error.
so I wonder why the value of extension_dir can't be modified.

Comment: FYI, PHP on the command line runs a completely separate binary from the Apache module, so restarting Apache is irrelevant.  I believe the output of `phpinfo()` in the browser is likely also unrelated to the functionality of CLI PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the question.

Just because php -i and phpinfo() in the web script using different php.ini files.

I seriously take a look at the different output of php -i and phpinfo().

Here comes the difference:

**phpinfo()** :

> Server API    Apache 2.0 Handler
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path
> C:\Windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File
> D:\phpnow\php-5.2.10-Win32\php-apache2handler.ini

**php -i**

> Server API => Command Line Interface
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>  C:\Windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File  => (none)

the key problem is php -i loads nothing, but expecting a php.ini.

Comment: `php -c D:\phpnow\php-5.2.10-Win32\php-apache2handler.ini get.php` will probably work, then.  And/or you can probably `cp D:\phpnow\php-5.2.10-Win32\php-apache2handler.ini C:\Windows\php.ini`.  I wouldn't really consider either of those production-grade solutions, but it should at least get you started.

Comment: On Linux, instead of copy, you can create an symlink to the main php.ini on the CLI directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try copying php.ini file in c:\windows directory. I am using PHP 5.3.5. and I had the same problem in Windows. When I copied php.ini file in c:\windows, extension_dir was properly set and my graphics program started working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `extension=php_curl.dll` to php.ini?

FWIW, the best way to check phpinfo for CLI is probably:

```
$ php -i | fgrep -i curl
Configure Command =>  '/SourceCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-44.4/php/configure'  '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-ldap=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--enable-cli' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--enable-trans-sid' '--with-xml' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-dbx' '--enable-sockets' '--with-iodbc=/usr' '--with-curl=/usr' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--without-pear'
curl
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => libcurl/7.16.3 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
$
```

`php -i` is basically the CLI equivalent of `phpinfo()`

Also, double check that PHP CLI is configured to use the same php.ini (or if it's using a different file, ensure that you've edited that one as well).  Sometimes PHP can be set up with different php.inis depending on how PHP is invoked -- I believe debian and Ubuntu do this, specifically.

Determining the php.ini file in use:

```
$ php -i | fgrep Configuration
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
$
```

or

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php.d/dbase.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/imagick.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/pgsql.ini,
/etc/php.d/tidy.ini,
/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

Comment: i've deleted the semicolon ";" on the line : extension=php_curl.dll,
i can clearly say that curl extension did enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Frank Farmer,how do i know which php.ini that php -i command was used?

Comment: Added a note re: determining the php.ini file in use to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working with php 5.4.4. with Windows 7 and Apache 2.2.
Running phpinfo() showed that the value assigned to `extension_dir` wasn't matching the setting in php.ini

But php.ini **was** certainly being read.

My suspicion is that extension_dir needs a reboot in Windows and the PATH set. 
Other settings in php.ini just need an Apache restart.